# Nonsense error when increasing LightSource angle?

Tags: lighting, unreal-4, angles

My project has a **Light Source** and a **Sky Sphere Blueprint**.

The rotation on the y axis (Light Source) defines the position of the sun (Sky Sphere Blueprint).

**Character Blueprint (increases by 10 degrees on the y-axis rotation of Light Source, the updates the position of the sun):**

[image]

**When you click the button (Angulo, circled in pink), the angle increases by 10 and works to a certain moment:**

[image]

**Image with angle increased by 10:**

[image]

**When it reaches 100 degrees, it starts to go wrong. Each time I click the button it goes from 90 to 100 and vice versa in an infinite loop:**

[image]

[image]

I've already tried to turn it around, subtracting instead of adding, but at one point it also gives error (in the case with 110 degrees).

Comment: Sounds like you might be experiencing an issue of angle wrap-around when using Euler angles, [similar to this issue a user encountered using these angles in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/165510/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory I saw your answer and it opened my mind, helping me find a solution. Soon I will post how I solved my specific problem.

Comment: @DMGregory I posted a answer based on the help I received through your comment and answer. Feel free to complement it or post your own answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **@DMGregory** comment and also on his answer given in another question.

**Question link where he gave the answer that helped me:**

[Why rotating an object only on its local X axis result in sudden 180 degrees changes in Y and Z axis rotation values](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/165505/why-rotating-an-object-only-on-its-local-x-axis-result-in-sudden-180-degrees-cha/165510#165510)

I stopped using the value coming from the rotation of **Light Source**. I have stored the desired value in a variable and set it directly in the rotation of the **Light Source**.

**First I did a test using a switch and it worked:**

[image]

**To optimize this, I used a structure and a data table:**

[image]