# How to limit camera pitch (x rotation) between two angles

Tags: unity, c#, camera, rotation

I use this script rotate the camera on its local X axis:

```
 float v = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
 transform.Rotate(-v, 0, 0);
```

Right now this lets the player look up & down without limit, wrapping around a full 360 degrees. How can I limit this so they can look only 90 degrees up or 90 degrees down from the horizon?

Comment: Do you want to limit the speed of change over time between two limiting rates, or limit the absolute orientation between two limiting angles? If the latter, have you reviewed [previous questions about limiting or clamping rotation angles in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+limit+angle)?

Comment: this for Fps camera but When I rotate to the top it is going 360 I want limit

Comment: This script Makes player  looks top and down but There is no limit it  reach to 360 I'm trying to make it between 90  -90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of `Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max)`. Ordinarily I'd recommend caution calculating new orientations from Euler angles, but for camera orientation it's typically safe enough. You might want to pull back slightly from 90, say 80 degrees, so you don't hit nasty behaviour right at the poles.

```
// Correct for deltaTime so your behaviour is framerate independent.
// (You may need to increase your speed as it's now measured in degrees per second, not per frame)
float angularIncrement = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime;

// Get the current rotation angles.
Vector3 eulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles;

// Returned angles are in the range 0...360. Map that back to -180...180 for convenience.
if(eulerAngles.x > 180f)
    eulerAngles.x -= 360f;

// Increment the pitch angle, respecting the clamped range.
eulerAngles.x = Mathf.Clamp(eulerAngles.x - angularIncrement, -90f, 90f);

// Orient to match the new angles.
transform.localEulerAngles = eulerAngles;
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it works

Comment: I think there's something wrong i have try min 0 max 70 This gives me from feet to half screen 0 but if i put min to -30 and up Nothing happens

Comment: This is one of the hazards of Euler angles. [The engine has to wrap them somewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/165510/39518) - here it picked to wrap the x angle to lie in 0...360, but we want it in -180...180 - add the `if` line shown above to map it in a more convenient range.

Comment: Thanks you Again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` condition such as:

```
float v = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
if (v > 100)  then //100 your limit
    {v= 50}
else 
    {v=30}
```

or you can use `math.sign` function which gives you +1,0,-1

> if the result for your case v > 0 it returns +1
>
> if it is zero than 0
>
> if it is negative then it is -1

you can limit your camera by that way.