# Unity - change only z axis rotation to 0

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have a child where I want the `rotation` to work like `(parentRot, parentRot, 0)`.

So first I set its `localRotation` to 0, meaning it will get the parents rotation: `child.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;`

But how can I make sure the world rotation (not local) value of the z axis stays at 0?

Comment: I've notice that you tagged this question both as `C#` and `UnityScript`. Are you sure you need an answer which explains how to do this in the old, [deprecated](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/) UnityScript scripting language? If you only need a solution for writing Unity scripts in C#, please don't use that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to think of it:

First, we figure out which direction in the parent space points toward world "up":

```
Vector3 parentSpaceUp = transform.parent.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3.up);
```

Then we orient ourselves to point forward in the parent's local coordinate, while aligning our own up vector as close as possible to this vertical:

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, parentSpaceUp);
```

Wherever possible, I like to use direction vectors and quaternions over Euler angles, both to avoid unnecessary trig functions, and also to make sure the code doesn't exhibit [bugs at edge cases where the Euler angles wrap around](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/165510/39518).

Comment: excellent point, a much more elegant answer, IMO. There certainly is a good amount of overhead in converting Euler angles to quaternions. My answer was an attempt to provide a solution to mirror the question as best as possible for someone who may not be entirely familiar with quaternion algebra. I vote for this though, for elgance reasons. - Oh, and for the record, the solution I provided would not experience gimbal-lock related issues, as a quaternion can be described using euler angles and vice-versa. The trouble would come when accumulating euler angles, instead of direct conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but this does precisely what you described.

```
public class AxisLock : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 target;
        target.x = transform.parent.eulerAngles.x;
        target.y = transform.parent.eulerAngles.y;
        target.z = 0;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(target);
    }
}
```