# Euler Angle X is wrong after using Quaternion.LookRotation

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

I have an direction that I want the local player hub & camera to rotate at.
The game handles this by using euler angles which Y represents the hub rotation on the horizontal axis & X represents the camera rotation on the vertical axis.

The min-max range for vertical is -88 to 88 & min-max range for horizontal is 0 to 360

Here is the code I am using the create euler angles that will look onto the direction

```
Vector2 CalcEuler(Vector3 dst, Vector3 src)
{
    //dst is target position, src is maincamera position
    Quaternion quat = Quaternion.LookRotation((dst - 
                                            src), Vector3.right);
    Vector3 euler = quat.get_eulerAngles();
    return { euler.y, euler.x };
}
```

the horizontal axis(euler.y) returned from CalcEuler is perfect and rotates the hub to lock onto the specified direction. However the vertical axis(euler.x) returned from CalcEuler only works if the direction.Y value is the same as src.Y. If it isnt then itll shoot up into really high numbers past 200 and even sometimes at 359.99.

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: I found something some guy did on github for his rotation. After doing Quaternion.Lookrotation he did this

```
euler.x = (src.y < dst.y) ? (-360.f + euler.x) : euler.x;
```

however this does not change anything for me

SOLVED: Both answers fix the problem

Comment: Keep in mind that [Euler angles are a convenient fiction for data entry](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/165510/39518), but internally the real orientation of an object is a quaternion. [I recommend never using individual Euler angle components converted from a quaternion as an input to a calculation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/201970/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory I have come up with a solution but its a mere brute forced method that only works if the direction euler pitch is 0. Hope to find more info soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce angular limits, keep it in terms of angles from the start. Don't count on an automatic conversion from quaternions to Euler angles to give you angles in a specific range, because there are many Euler angle triplets corresponding to any one quaternion, and any mapping we pick will be wrong for at least one use case.

```cs
public static Vector2 GetClampedEuler(Vector3 lookTarget, Vector3 lookOrigin, float maxPitch) {
    Vector3 direction = (lookTarget - lookOrigin).normalized;

    // Get rotation in horizontal plane in range -180...180
    float yaw = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    // Remap to 0...360
    if (yaw < 0f) yaw += 360f;

    // Get angle below horizontal in range -90...90
    float pitch = Mathf.Asin(-direction.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    
    // Enforce pitch limits
    return new Vector2(yaw, Mathf.Clamp(pitch, -maxPitch, maxPitch));
}
```

Comment: This entire problem could be solved by setting the imaginary phase angle component of the quaternion to 0 prior to conversion to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: The ambiguity is not from the quaternion side. Quaternions provide a double cover over the set of 3D orientations, but each quaternion maps to exactly one orientation. Euler/Tait-Bryan angles form a countably infinite cover - there's an unlimited number of angle triplets you can write to express a given orientation: e.g. (180, 180, 0) and (0, 0, 180) both refer to the same orientation, and are both valid conversion results from the quaternion (0, 0, 1, 0). The trouble is one stores part of the rotation as pitch, and the other stores it entirely as roll, messing up code looking at only x.

Comment: So if your code expects one Euler angle conversion, but the library picks a different, equally-correct one, you can get an unintuitive result. Say you're clamping on the x-axis, but the library decided to smuggle out some of that x rotation as y/z instead, or spat out an angle in 0-360 when your code was written to expect -180 to +180, or things of that nature. There's no ambiguity about which orientation it maps to, it's just expressed it in an inconvenient way for the clamping you wanted to do. [See past examples of this kind of issue](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/183777/39518).

Comment: The quaternion has a hidden value, via the complex plane, that determines the output angle.  Not some mysterious "library pick". Imagine each point on the unit sphere having a direction associated(complex value), that direction points to the resultant vector.

Comment: If you'd like to post an answer showing how this can be applied to solve the problem, please feel free.

Comment: ty this fixed my other error. It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to isolate the heading of a look direction then zero out the up and use the atan2 function directly.

```
vector3 dir = dst - src;
heading = atan2(dir.y, dir.x); //assuming the up/down is along z and 0 heading is along x, swap axis as appropriate
pitch = atan2(hypot(dir.x, dir.y), dir.z);
```

Though you will need to take care when hypot(dir.x, dir.y) is very small, aka when the pitch angle would exceed the bounds.

Though frankly I dislike computing back to angles using the arctan/arccos just to be put into a rotate which will put it straight into a cos and sin.

instead you can just pass the look direction directly through to whatever does the rotating hand have it figure out the correct transform operation based on just `(dst - src).normalized()`

Comment: no longer increases to values past 88 but if my camera is higher or lower than the target position then itll be off by a certain amount