# Rotate FPS Controller without Mouse

Tags: unity, rotation, first-person-shooter

I'm trying to set up a game with portals in it. I've been struggling for a while now to rotate the Player. I've tried Quat.Slerp, Quat.AngleAxis, and Quat.Euler. But through rigorous testing I discovered that the MouseLook function in my FPS Controller script is the reason the Player isn't rotating. The player is being rotated, but half a frame later, the MouseLook script resets the Player's rotation.
How can I rotate the player without letting the MouseLook function of my FPS Controller script get in the way?

```
void MouseLook()
{   mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * sensX * Time.deltaTime;
    mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * sensY * Time.deltaTime;
        
    yRot += mouseX;    xRot -= mouseY;
    xRot = Mathf.Clamp(xRot, -50f, 50f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, yRot, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines

> ```
> yRot += mouseX;
> xRot -= mouseY;
> ```

Are saying "Take the previous rotation values from mouse movement and add the latest mouse movement to them"

Which is then applied by this line:

> ```
> transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, yRot, 0);
> ```

The easiest option would be to rotate the player by changing `xRot` and `yRot`, so the next time `MouseLook()` is called, it's taking your manual rotation into account.

Failing that, you could either read the current rotation (might become complex if the player is ever non-vertical) or having another variable to track manual rotation  separately from mouse rotation and sum the two together when setting `transform.rotation`

Comment: Can you show how you would take a manual rotation and convert it to the corresponding xRot and yRot values to set?

Comment: @DMGregory It's a simple addition, but you're welcome to edit it into my answer if you think it's needed.

Comment: if you already have an angle delta, sure. What if you have a target orientation as a quaternion, or a target facing vector, and need to distill that down to these two angle values? That's a little more than just addition, which is why I think it would be worth demoing explicitly.

Comment: @Basic I'm attempting to manually rotate the player in a separate script. So, suppose I make ```xRot``` and ```yRot``` public, I'd be able to change their values from my other script? Better yet, I think I'll try performing the rotation within my FPS controller script...brb    (EDIT) K im back. Its not gonna work coz im doing math from a separate script. Unless I can access one script from another???

Comment: You can access one script from another, but before that, why not edit your question to show us what you're doing in the other script? How does the player rotation work?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I probably should edit my query and show *how* I'm rotating the player, but making ```xRot```and ```yRot``` public and static did the trick! Omfg works so good.

Comment: Comment again when you have and I'll show you how to integrate it into one script (or communicate between scripts if that's more appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to update your FPS Controller script with a public method something like this:

```
public void RotateCameraToFace(Vector3 direction) {
    Vector3 d = direction.normalized;
    xRot = Mathf.Asin(-d.y);
    yRot = Mathf.Atan2(d.x, d.z);
}
```

This updates the internal angle-tracking variables so they'll produce an orientation that looks along `direction`.

If you have your desired orientation as a quaternion, you can call `controller.RotateCameraToFace(orientation * Vector3.forward)` to use this same code.

You could also try unpacking `xRot` and `yRot` from `orientation.eulerAngles`, though I wouldn't recommend it. [You can get some awkward wrap-around cases when using computed Euler angles as input for another computation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/165510/39518), so my standard practice is to compute the angles myself in a way I can control and verify has wrap-arounds handled in a way that works for my use case.